# String.Join possible to join only 1 specific character?

Tags: c#, string

```
List<string> names = new List<string>() { "John", "Anna", "Monica" };
var result = String.Join("", names.ToArray());
```

I would like to Join only 1 specific character from each string. Let's say, the 3rd one. Without loop if possible.

```
// result = "hnn"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To Add to the Linq answers, the simplest one would likely be:

```
var result = new string(names.Where(name => name.Count() >= 3).Select(x => x[2]).ToArray());
```

To break that down, you first filter the list to make sure there is no name that is too short:

```
var filteredNames = names.Where(name => name.Count() >= 3);
```

Then you can actually select each corresponding character in the filtered names:

```
var resultingCharacters = filteredNames.Select(name => name[2]).ToArray;
```

And you can just seamlessly chain those calls together to create the solution named above.
Also you don't even need a Join in this case because you can just pass the resulting char array into a string constructor:

```
var result = new string(resultingCharacters);
```

You can also easily extract that to a function:

```
public static string JoinNthCharacters(List<string> names, int n) {
    return new("", names.Where(name => name.Count() >= n).Select(name => name[n]).ToArray());
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Hello probably you want something like this:

```
List<string> names = new List<string>() { "John", "Anna", "Monica" };
const int specificCharacter = 2;

    var result = names.Where(name => specificCharacter < name.Length)
                      .Aggregate(string.Empty, (current, name) => current + name[specificCharacter]);
```

`where` is for you do not get a System.IndexOutOfRangeException
And `Aggregate` to "join" the string. Here is the link with more information about it.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.aggregate?view=net-6.0

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with LINQ:

```
List<string> names = new List<string>() { "John", "Anna", "Monica" };
var result = String.Join
    (
        "",
        from x in names
        select x[2]
    );
```